# Android : HashMap is showing only last array item in a Listview field

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

I'm prsing information from a `json` file and showing data in a custom `ListView`. Now, I have an `Array` named `authors`. Where authors are multiple. But, in `ListView` I can only see the last authors name or last array item . 
How can I show all items ? Here is my code

```
            for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) 
            {
                HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);

                String topic = jsonObject.getString("topic");

                String type = jsonObject.getString("type");

                String title = jsonObject.getString("title");

                String absData = jsonObject.getString("abstract");


               JSONArray getAuthorsArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("authors"));

                for(int a =0 ; a < getAuthorsArray.length(); a++){
                    JSONObject getJSonObj = (JSONObject)getAuthorsArray.get(a);
                    String authordName = getJSonObj.getString("name");
                    Log.e("Name", authordName);
                    temp.put(KEY_AUTHOR, authordName);
                }


                temp.put(KEY_TOPIC, topic);
                temp.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
                temp.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                temp.put(KEY_ABSTRACT,absData);



                list.add(temp);

            }
            }
            simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.abstract_items, from, new int[]{R.id.abTopic,R.id.abType,R.id.abTitle,R.id.SubTitle});
            setListAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Comment: Are you sure the list you're passing to the adapter has more than one element? What does the debugger say? And aside: you shouldn't be doing all this work in main thread. This might lead to an ANR. Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) better.

Comment: Nope. Only the last one is passing in the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
 temp.put(KEY_AUTHOR, authordName);
```

That's probably why. You are iterating over the all authors but `HashMap` will override values and only the last one is being saveed.

As I understand you are getting back a JSON response with an array of JSONObject. Each JSONObject holding some info and a sub-JSONArray of associated authors.

The easiest approach could be just building `ArrayList<JSONObject>` and extending `BaseAdapter` implementing an adapter of your own. It's very easy. For large collections of data search on ViewHolder pattern, for optimization.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you suggest me  any resources that might be helpful for me.

Comment: Search for any project that uses a custom adapter and you're good to go. Every Android project in my github uses it. Just make sure to reuse `convertView` and not inflate view for each item in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
        'HashMap<String, String> temp;
  for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) 
        {
            temp = new HashMap<String,String>();

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);

            String topic = jsonObject.getString("topic");

            String type = jsonObject.getString("type");

            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");

            String absData = jsonObject.getString("abstract");


           JSONArray getAuthorsArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("authors"));

            for(int a =0 ; a < getAuthorsArray.length(); a++){
                JSONObject getJSonObj = (JSONObject)getAuthorsArray.get(a);
                String authordName = getJSonObj.getString("name");
                Log.e("Name", authordName);
                temp.put(KEY_AUTHOR, authordName);
            }


            temp.put(KEY_TOPIC, topic);
            temp.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
            temp.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            temp.put(KEY_ABSTRACT,absData);



            list.add(temp);

        }
        }
        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.abstract_items, from, new int[]{R.id.abTopic,R.id.abType,R.id.abTitle,R.id.SubTitle});
        setListAdapter(simpleAdapter);'
```

you declare the "HashMap"line in above the onstart values.it will help for you.